# PHP Isn't Pulling Input From HTML Contact Form

Tags: javascript, php, html, contact-form

Here's my HTML code:

```html
<form method="POST" action="thank_you.php" novalidate>
              <div class="form-group"> 
    <label for="name">Full Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" required>
                <div class="valid-feedback">Looks good</div>
                <div class="invalid-feedback">Please enter your name</div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email">Email address</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="eg: email@email.com" required>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="url">Your Website</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="url" name="url" placeholder="eg: www.website.com">
              </div>
              <h4>Project Details</h4>
              <p>Please provide a brief description of your project, what your end goal is, and how I can help you achieve this goal.
                 Please, also specify what your budget is.</p>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="budget">Budget Amount</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="budget" name="budget" placeholder="eg: $2,000" required>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="project">Project Description</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" id="project" name="project" rows="5" required></textarea>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="completion">Desired Completion Date</label>
                <select class="form-control" id="completion" name="completion" required>
                  <option>Please select</option>
                  <option>As soon as possible</option>
                  <option>1-3 weeks</option>
                  <option>1-3 months</option>
                  <option>4-6 months</option>
                  <option>To be determined</option>
                </select>
              </div>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit">SEND</button>
            </form>
```

And here's my PHP:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email =  $_POST['email'];
$url =  $_POST['url']; 
$budget =  $_POST['budget'];
$project =  $_POST['project'];
$completion =  $_POST['completion'];

$to = "jb@jbwebsitesolutions.com";
$subject = "New Request";
$body = "Please see details below.";


mail($to, $subject, $body);
 ?>
```

What happens is once  the form is submitted, only everything in the mail(function) displays, but not the input one. So Can somebody please show me where I went wrong and how I can fix it?

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: Is this the real `$body` content? When this is the real content, all your form data is not send at all. Did you try using `var_dump($_POST)` after submitting your form? Just to see, if your post data is there ...

Comment: Please explain  your problem, which data are not pulling? What you are expecting to happen? 

Did you try to debug using var_dump($_POST) or var_dump($_REQUEST)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently your code is incomplete, You should include the submission data to $body

like this:

```
$body = "Please see details below.";
$body .= '\r\n Name :'.$name.'\r\n';
$body .= '\r\n Email :'.$email.'\r\n';
```

also the option tag must have a value attribute

```
  <select class="form-control" id="completion" name="completion" required>
              <option value="">Please select</option>
              <option value="As soon as possible">As soon as possible</option>
              <option value="1-3 weeks">1-3 weeks</option>
              <option value="1-3 months">1-3 months</option>
              <option value="4-6 months">4-6 months</option>
              <option value="To be determined">To be determined</option>
            </select>
```

Comment: Midhun1993, thanks! That worked! Now I need to figure out how to not let it show the <br/> tag.

Comment: @Jerome sorry but i think that you still need to check if the post values are set in the first place using `isset()`

Comment: Use `\r\n` instead of  `<br>`

Comment: The \r\n works.  You have to use double quotes so they're not read as strings. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single for the info.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass POST data into $body tag for example :

```
$to = "jb@jbwebsitesolutions.com";
    $subject = "New Request";
    $body = "";
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email =  $_POST['email'];
    $url =  $_POST['url']; 
    $budget =  $_POST['budget'];
    $project =  $_POST['project'];
    $completion =  $_POST['completion'];
    $body = "Hello ". $name."," .'<br/>';
    $body .= $email;
    $body .= "Your bugdet is :" . $budget;

    // Always set content-type when sending HTML email
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

    // More headers
    $headers .= 'From: <webmaster@example.com>' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Cc: myboss@example.com' . "\r\n";

    mail($to,$subject,$body,$headers);
```